# Preventing Right Click Option in Web Application

Tags: javascript, web-applications, browser

Why do many web applications (like Bank sites) prevent the right click property in the browser?

Comment: Because they have TheDailyWTF-grade "consultants" that sell snake oil knowledge at high rates to the banks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this question belongs more in UX.SE, there is no good answer. Nor I or no one else have seen a good reason to do this. Some think that it makes it hard to copy text, and use it as DRM. Some do it because they think that it's cool. But it is only Bad Design.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security concerns though its not true.

Some designers think if right click is disabled then you can't inspect source code and inject js snippet.

Comment: Even if right click **is** disabled you can inspect html code and invoke JavaScript functions.

Comment: agree...have modified post.